# How do i insert html into my table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to save formatted text into a table, and i use this nice rich text editor that outputs HTML. When I run it i get:

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token
>   line offset = 31,Token in error = < ]

My command looks like:

```
new SqlCeCommand("UPDATE Bio SET text = " + form["textbox"].Replace("\"", "&quot;") + " WHERE id = " + ViewBag.Id, conn)
```

But I guess it does not like <>, what do I need to replace? Do the same with the quote as with the <>? Any function that escapes it all?

Comment: use parameterized sql. such code is unsecure for SQL Injection.plus if this code intended for users. letting html or jscript is dangerous too. XSS attack

Comment: try using a parameter in the statement rather than putting the value in-line

Comment: Hows you DB? You should use varchar(MAX) or store as bytes. There's a issue, use SqlCommand Builder to do the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here for an example of passing the text you want to insert as a parameter:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcecommand.parameters(v=vs.100).aspx

As recommended by MattD - here is example code.  Note that I did not actually run this, if there is a syntax issue, leave a note and I'll fix it.  This should get you 99% of the way in any case.

Also note: it is ALWAYS a good idea to use parameters this way, rather than appending literal text into a sql query.  This eliminates the possibility of a SQL injection error or hack, where someone might maliciously enter text that finishes your SQL and then adds their own SQL that will also get executed.

```
SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("UPDATE Bio SET text = @htmlText WHERE id = @id", conn);

SqlCeParameter param;

// NOTE:
// For optimal performance, make sure you always set the parameter
// type and the maximum size - this is especially important for non-fixed
// types such as NVARCHAR or NTEXT; In case of named parameters, 
// SqlCeParameter instances do not need to be added to the collection
// in the order specified in the query; If however you use ? as parameter
// specifiers, then you do need to add the parameters in the correct order
//
param = new SqlCeParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
command.Parameters.Add(param);
param = new SqlCeParameter("@htmlText", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1);
command.Prepare();

//Set the values and the length of the string parameter
command.Parameters[0].Value = ViewBag.Id;
command.Parameters[1].Value = form["textbox"];
command.Parameters[1].Size = form["textbox"].Length;



// Execute the SQL statement
//
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Could you flesh this out with a sample written using the code he's already provided, as well as an explanation as to why he should do it this way? A single link answer doesn't really provide much of a good answer for the purposes of StackOverflow.